# doctrine avoid automatic hydration

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm working with an old version of DoctrineExtension.Tree and I don't have buildTree. So I'd like to do the same but I keep running into a problem:
Everytime I use findHierarchy(see below) and iterate on all my children in the hierarchy it gets everything twice. Because Doctrine still queries to find the children (even though I loaded them in find Hierarchy) Here is some useful code:

The two functions in my entity

```
/**
 * Add children
 *
 * @param BGCom\MontreuxBundle\Entity\Category $children
 */
public function addChildren(\BGCom\MontreuxBundle\Entity\Category $children)
{
    $children->setParent($this);
    $this->children[] = $children;
}

/**
 * Get children
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getChildren()
{
    return $this->children;
}
```

find hierarchy in my repo:

```
public function findHierarchy() {
    $qb = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('node')
        ->where('node.lvl < 2')
        ->andWhere('node.in_menu = 1')
        ->orderBy('node.root, node.lvl', 'ASC');

    // set hint to translate nodes
    $query = $qb->getQuery()->setHint(
        Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER,
        'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker'
    );
    $res = $query->getResult();
    //Now build the right entity
    // build tree in english
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    // We rebuild the tree
    $parent = array();
    while($i < count($res)) {
        $cur = $res[$i];
        $parent[] = $cur;
        $i++;
        while ($i < count($res) && $res[$i]->getRoot() === $cur->getId()) {
            $cur->addChildren($res[$i]);
            $i++;
        }
    }
    return $parent;
}
```

my view:

```
{% for root in trees %}
<li>
    <a href="{{ category_path(root) }}">{{ root.name }}</a>
    <div class="box blue-gradient">
    <ul class="lvl1">
       {% for twig in root.getChildren() %}
           <li><a href="{{ category_path(twig)}}">
               {{ twig.name }}
           </a></li>
       {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </div>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

So to be clear: Is there a way to avoid doctrine from querying if some children are already present in the Entity?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine2 will never instantiate 2 instances of the same database row.

You probably have the same object twice.

You could avoid setting a `Category` twice in the `$children` array by doing this:

```
public function addChildren(\BGCom\MontreuxBundle\Entity\Category $children)
{
    $children->setParent($this);

    if (!$this->children->has($children)) {
        $this->children[] = $children;
    }   
}
```

Comment: well Doctrine queries the database even though children is already loaded. I want to avoid that